# Postfix term in SQL Server Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) article, 'CONTAINS' TSQL function have an argument called prefix_term, the documentations says:

> < prefix_term >
>
> ```
> Specifies a match of words or phrases beginning with the specified
> ```
>
> text. Enclose a prefix term in double
>   quotation marks ("") and add an
>   asterisk (*) before the ending
>   quotation mark, so that all text
>   starting with the simple term
>   specified before the asterisk is
>   matched.

Well, that's prefix, if I search "Ira*" it finds "Iranian, Iran, Iraq, Irascible, etc.".

But I'm looking for postfix term, so if I search "*ran" then I expect to see Iran, Trimaran, etc. in results.

How can I do that?

[UPDATE]

I've such term in ArticleContent column:

```
f5_Iran_three_islands
```

This query catches it:

```
Select Code,ArticleContent from Articles Where ArticleContent Like '%Ira%'
```

But I can't catch this row by this query:

```
Select Code FROM Articles WHERE CONTAINS(ArticleContent, '"*Ira*"')
```

[/UPDATE]

Answer (score 1):

This is, I think, a common misconception when it comes to full text search in SQL Server.

Full Text Search enables searching for entire words as well as a number of other things. From the CONTAINS documentation

CONTAINS can search for:

> A word or phrase.
>
> The prefix of a word or phrase.
>
> A word near another word.
>
> A word inflectionally generated from another (for example, the word
> drive is the inflectional stem of drives, drove, driving, and driven).
>
> A word that is a synonym of another word using a thesaurus (for
> example, the word "metal" can have synonyms such as "aluminum" and
> "steel").

So just like with normal indexes on text strings, you can do prefix searching.

Neither full text search, nor normal SQL Server indexes, support "postfix" or "contains" searching within a word or text string. So no leading wildcards, essentially.

Note that the same limitations apply to CONTAINSTABLE:

CONTAINSTABLE is useful for the same kinds of matches as the CONTAINS predicate and uses the same search conditions as CONTAINS.

I imagine these limitations exist because of the way indexes are logically stored in SQL Server - as b-trees, where it's very easy to "jump" or "seek" to the different parts of an index based on the start of the data in the indexed column.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, the docs state that only prefix terms are possible in this manner.
[MSDN: CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

If you wish to use postfix terms you could either use the standard wildcard searches (LIKE etc), or consider writing a .Net stored procedure that utilises regex searching. I've done it before and the writing of the sp wasn't so hard, though the loading of it into the server was a pain (.Net 2, SQL Server 2005).

Answer (score 0):

Iran :) into the same problem. You can create a reversed copy of the text in another column, then also look for a reversed value.

```
declare @value varchar(50), @value_contains varchar(53), @value_contains_reverse varchar(53)
set @value = '20602019';
set @value_contains = '"'+@value+'*"';
set @value_contains_reverse = '"'+reverse(@value)+'*"';
select charindex(@value, matchstring) from Table 
where contains(matchstring, @value_contains) or contains(matchstring_reverse,@value_contains_reverse)
```